# First PC Build - Screen gets no signal

Tags: desktop-computer, computer-building, computer-behavior

I just finished building my first PC and wanted to install the OS.
As I turned it on, the fans started spinning, LED's on the motherboard light up, but no signal on the display.

Even the LED's on my keyboard light up after a while and the Caps Lock light toggles when pressing the corresponding key.
Still I don't get any signal on my display.

I already tried the following:

1. Reset the CMOS
2. Tried changing memory slots/booting with one memory card
3. Made sure all cables a plugged in correctly
4. Unplugged HDD and SSD
5. Tried different monitor and different output (HDMI / VGA)

I can't seem to find the problem, does anyone of the Pro's here know what the problem could be?

Specs:

**Motherboard**:
 - ASUS Prime B350-Plus

**CPU**:
 - Ryzen 5 1600

**RAM**:
 - Corsair Vengeance DDR4 2x8GB

**PSU**:
 - EVGA 650GQ Gold

Comment: Does it POST?  Is the CPU correctly seated in the socket?  Is the GPU correctly seated in the slot and known to work correctly?  Try a known good PSU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved someone at tomshardware told me that I need a Graphics Card because the Ryzen 5 doesn't have integrated graphics